# Magento 2 : Which area to add Di.xml for graphql?

Tags: magento2

In which area i should add di.xml file for "Graphql calls" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your `di.xml` at:

> {Vendor}/{module}/etc/graphql/di.xml

For reference you can check :

> vendor/magento/module-graph-ql/etc/graphql/di.xml

Comment: I do not see this area in documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html

Comment: please refer: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html#magento-area-types

Comment: Thanks, so if graphql call is their then the override in di.xml will work else wont right ?

Comment: It should Work, You can refer any core graphql module from magento 2

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: welcome @devhs :)